# PATH in post-receive hook doesn't contain PATH as set in bashrc

Tags: bash, path, git-post-receive

How can I set the PATH on Ubuntu in a way where its variables that I set are also set in a post-receive script? Currently I'm doing it via the `~/.bashrc` file like this:

`export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"`

but can't see any change in the `PATH` if I print it from the hook. Therefore, if I try to execute the command in question in the hook, I get

`remote: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sqlcmd': 'sqlcmd'`

So the only solution I see right now is defining it again in the post-receive hook itself, like this:

`export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"`

Is there a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're looking for a better way, please edit your post to include the specific code that shows the way you're currently doing it.

Comment: This feels like a little bit of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  I'm guessing that you suspect the PATH is wrong because some executable or other isn't being found, correct?  So what is that executable?  The PATH in your hook script just has to define a PATH that includes all the executables the hook script will use.  If you can enumerate all the executables it needs, then you'll be very far along in constructing a `PATH=` command that includes those.  What executable(s) is/are failing in the hook script?

Comment: I suspect the root issue is that the initial value of `$PATH` is different when you login and run .bashrc vs. when the hook script runs.  Either inventory the list of executables your hook uses, and specify a path that will allow it to find those executables; OR you can reduce/eliminate your reliance on `PATH` in the hook scripts and specify absolute `PATH`s to the executables you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and the extensive answers, I appreciate it. My main confusion is why the path is different when I do a normal interactive bash session over ssh vs in the hook script. So normally, when I need to call an executable in an interactive bash session, I add its path to `PATH` in `.bashrc` if it isn't there yet. But this doesn't add it to the path for the git hook. Is there a file other than `.bashrc` where I can permanently set the `PATH` for git hooks? Or, in case of an X-Y-problem, is there a different, better approach altogether?

Comment: In case there isn't, I'll probably go with your suggestion of just calling the program needed (namely, sqlcmd) by its actual absolute path without messing with the `PATH` variable, that sounds like it would make most sense right now. Still, if you can provide any deeper insight on why the `PATH` is different in an interactive bash session vs in a git hook, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: The path can differ greatly between an interactive login and say, a cron job, or a job spawned by, I presume in your case, a web or git daemon.  So you need to look at the needs of your script and set a path that addresses the executables your script runs.  I would guess the script is emitting message to stderr, but they may be getting discarded if the script runs with no terminal attached.  Try modifying your script to capture its stderr to a file like /tmp/git-hook.err so you can see those error messages.  And if you like, edit your question to include those error messages.

Comment: As for the "why" part, it's just the way bash works.  The man page documents that for **interactive** shells (when a terminal is attached), bash reads .bashrc at start-up.  For non-interactive shells (like scripts), it does not read .bashrc.  Also the .bashrc read by an interactive bash shell belongs to the user running the shell, so even if the hook has **was** interactive, it would likely be running under the **www** or **git** user account, not your own account.

Comment: OK that makes sense with the interactive shells. Is there a configuration file that is read in non-interactive shells?

Comment: A quick read of the bash man page says that it will look for an environment variable `BASH_ENV` and treat that as a (full, absolute) filename to read and execute.

Comment: OK so I've put a command in the hook to print `BASH_ENV` and it doesn't print anything. But when I log in on a normal ssh session on that machine, `BASH_ENV` is empty too... Is this the way it's supposed to be? Because the ssh session does read `~/.bashrc`, but `BASH_ENV` is empty... How can that be?

Comment: The ssh shell is interactive, therefore .bashrc is read.  The hook script is not interactive, so .bashrc is not read.  **So just set the PATH inside the hook script.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a small bit of file setup:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/dir1 /tmp/dir2
$ date > /tmp/dir1/foo
$ date > /tmp/dir2/bar
```

Now, consider a simple script:

```
$ chmod 755 foo.sh; cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh

# intentionally set an inadequate PATH:

export PATH=""    

# script to 'ls' two dirs, show that output, and show the diff of the two.

ls /tmp/dir1 > temp1
ls /tmp/dir2 > temp2

echo /tmp/dir1:
cat temp1

echo /tmp/dir2:
cat temp2

diff temp1 temp2
```

The script is well-formed syntactically, but let's see what happens:

```
$ ./foo.sh
./foo.sh: ls: not found
./foo.sh: ls: not found
/tmp/dir1:
./foo.sh: cat: not found
/tmp/dir2:
./foo.sh: cat: not found
./foo.sh: diff: not found
```

The path isn't sufficient for the script interpreter to find the executables the script wants to run.  Three separate executables fail to load: `ls`, `cat`, and `diff`.  So let's help it a little.  Since `ls` typically resides in the `/bin` directory, let's edit `PATH` to become:

```
export PATH="/bin"
```

and try again:

```
$ ./foo.sh
/tmp/dir1:
foo
/tmp/dir2:
bar
./foo.sh: diff: not found
```

Well, `ls` runs okay now.  That's progress.  And since `cat` also lives in /bin, adding /bin to the path killed two birds with one stone.  But `diff` still isn't being found, because `diff` lives in /usr/bin.  So let's add that to the PATH:

```
export PATH="/bin:/usr/bin"
```

and try again:

```
$ ./foo.sh 
/tmp/dir1:
foo
/tmp/dir2:
bar
1c1
< foo
---
> bar
```

Voila!  No more errors, because the `PATH` variable contains everything needed to allow the script interpreter to locate the executables that are called by the script.

The other way is to tell `PATH` to butt out and specify your own path to executables.  This method is sometimes handy when you might not trust or desire the "standard" executables, for whatever reason.  When structuring a script in this fashion, I prefer to use variables for the executables I want to reference, so that if^H^Hwhen the location changes, I can just change the variables and don't have to search the entire script for all the invocations of that executable.

```
$ chmod 755 bar.sh; cat bar.sh
#!/bin/sh

# intentionally set an inadequate PATH:

export PATH=""

# ls lives in /bin:
LS="/bin/ls"

# so does cat:
CAT="/bin/cat"

# but diff lives in /usr/bin:
DIFF="/usr/bin/diff"

# script to 'ls' two dirs, show that output, and show the diff of the two.

$LS /tmp/dir1 > temp1
$LS /tmp/dir2 > temp2

echo /tmp/dir1:
$CAT temp1

echo /tmp/dir2:
$CAT temp2

$DIFF temp1 temp2
```

And the output:

```
$ ./bar.sh
/tmp/dir1:
foo
/tmp/dir2:
bar
1c1
< foo
---
> bar
```

You can mix and match these approaches, by specifying a `PATH` that includes most things, and specifying absolute paths for the others, but your problem is arising because you have not done that.

You either need to specify a full and adequate `PATH` in your hook script, and/or specify absolute paths to the remaining executables (if any) that reside outside whatever `PATH` variable your hook script currently uses.