# Git post-receive hook not using ruby version specified by rbenv

Tags: ruby, bash, git, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I'm deploying code to an ubuntu server which I've declared as a git remote with `git push prod master`.

But it's using the wrong version of Ruby.

**Error**

```
Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.1
```

**Manually ssh'ing** onto the server and running code, it shows the correct version of ruby.

```
$ rbenv local #=> 2.7.1
$ rbenv global #=> 2.7.1
$ ruby -v #=> ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]
```

**post-receive hook**

```
#!/bin/bash

GIT_DIR=/home/me/appname_prod
WORK_TREE=/home/me/appname
export APPNAME_DATABASE_USER='appname'

export RAILS_ENV=production
. ~/.bash_profile

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to production..."
        mkdir -p $WORK_TREE
        git --work-tree=$WORK_TREE --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f
        mkdir -p $WORK_TREE/shared/pids $WORK_TREE/shared/sockets $WORK_TREE/shared/log

        # start deploy tasks
        cd $WORK_TREE
        bundle install
        rake db:create
        rake db:migrate
        rake assets:precompile
        sudo restart puma-manager
        sudo service nginx restart
        # end deploy tasks
        echo "Git hooks deploy complete"
    else
        echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing: only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

**.bash_profile**

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

**.bashrc**

```
...
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

**`$ type rbenv` returns**

```
rbenv is a function
rbenv () 
{ 
    local command;
    command="${1:-}";
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        shift;
    fi;
    case "$command" in 
        rehash | shell)
            eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")"
        ;;
        *)
            command rbenv "$command" "$@"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

I don't have a good understanding of code below the app level, so I'm not sure what is going wrong here.

Is there a way I might try to fix this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870771/path-in-post-receive-hook-doesnt-contain-path-as-set-in-bashrc) might help. My best guess is your post-receive hook may not have the full path set in .bashrc.

Comment: Check If anywhere in gemfile you have ruby version specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling same problem some years ago but with cron.

I think your `.bashrc` needs some details. `bundle` and `rake` commands are rbenv shims, but you are not loading them in your path.
`.bashrc`

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

and prefix your commands with shims path (I just took code from my crontab)

```sh
...
$HOME/.rbenv/shims/bundle install
$HOME/.rbenv/shims/rake db:create
$HOME/.rbenv/shims/rake db:migrate
$HOME/.rbenv/shims/rake assets:precompile
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by simply loading rbenv in the `post-receive` hook, rather than in `.bashrc`.

```
# hooks/post-receive

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```